# Scikit-learn: train/test split not reproducible

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn's `train_test_split` functionality and am getting different results when running the same code repeatedly:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
```

When I log the number of unique elements in `y_train`:

```
logger.info(len(set(y_train)))
```

I get different values on repeated runs (with no code changes).  I would have thought the `random_state` would ensure a deterministic split.

How can I ensure the same split each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The randomness is not caused by `train_test_split` as you can see if you run this minimal code multiple times:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x = [k for k in range(0, 50)]
y = [k for k in range(0, 50)]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=44)

print (x_train)
```

You probably have another source of randomness in your code. So maybe numpy/pandas is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The value you set the `random_state` (42 used in many scikit-learn examples) does not really matter, what is most important is that the value is the same always so you can validate your code multiple times.

There might be some other randomness present in your code that produces different result could you post your complete code.

Comment: It pulls from the same CSV every time